# Prevent webpage scroll on touch input for mobile devices

Tags: javascript, html, css, web, scroll

I'm creating a website that simulates an os (graphically speaking) for my graphic design portfolio - http://dreamstate.graphics/. This means that I need several of my elements to be draggable. Everything is working fine on a desktop computer, however, on mobile, the user can't drag elements without the entire website scrolling.

Tapping on elements works fine as a click event, so the website isn't unusable, but I'd like to be able to drag with touch input. I know this has been asked many times before, however, none of the solutions are working for me and I'm completely lost.

### What I've tried/my setup

In CSS I've hidden the overflows and made the positions fixed on my container element and the body:

```css
body, html {
  position: fixed;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

In Javascript I've prevented the default function of touchmove:

```js
document.addEventListener("touchmove", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault()
}, {
  passive: false
});
```

If I change the called function on the event listener to `alert("it works")`, I'm not being alerted so it may not be detecting `touchmove` events anyway. I do have video overlays, but they are set to `touch-action: none;`.

What am I doing wrong here and how can I prevent scrolling from interfering with touch functionality?

Answer (score 0):

Need to handle 3 events:"touchstart", "touchmove", and "touchend".

```
.addEventListener('touchstart', function(e){e.preventDefault();...});
.addEventListener('touchmove', function(e){e.preventDefault();...});
.addEventListener('touchend', function(e){e.preventDefault();...});
```

Comment: Wow thank you, I'm not sure why I didn't try this. This solution does prevent all touch inputs however, meaning the website really doesn't work on mobile. But, thankfully it stops that scrolling issue so this gets me somewhere. Is it possible to trigger a click event when it detects a touch event?

Comment: Is it possible to trigger a click event when it detects a touch event?
Yes, it is.

Answer (score 0):

```
<button id="myBtn">click</button>
<div id="doc1">
   <p>test click </p>   
</div>
<script>
var docElement1 = document.getElementById("doc1")
function testClick(){
  alert("Hello World!");
  e.preventDefault();
}
document.getElementById("myBtn").addEventListener("click", testClick);
var isMouseDown = false;
docElement1.onmousedown = function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  isMouseDown = true;
};
docElement1.onmouseup = function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  if(isMouseDown){
    //testClick();
    document.getElementById("myBtn").click();
  }
  isMouseDown = false;
};
</script>
```